# How to write this pattern in regex?

Tags: regex

Can you please help us to extract word from a sentence like:

> He's led U.S. efforts for government-centered management ever since, resulting in the  missions to the area.

How can we have:

```
He's 
led 
U.S. 
efforts 
for 
government-centered
management 
ever 
since
resulting 
in 
the  
missions 
to 
the 
area
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Edit and comment:

We thank all for your kind help.

Comment: You mean removing . and , from your phrase without removing the . in US ?

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can split on the regex

```
(?:(?<![A-Z])\.|,)?(\s+|$)
```

This splits on whitespace, optionally preceded by a dot/comma (but on the dot only if it's not preceded by an uppercase ASCII letter).

It will fail on edge cases like `etc.`, so if you have a list of those, you can work them into the regex if your regex engine supports variable repetition inside lookbehinds. Which one are you using?

E. g.

```
(?:(?<![A-Z]|\betc|\bca|\bapprox)\.|,)?(\s+|$)
```

would split

```
He's led U.S. efforts for management, resulting in approx. 3 times the missions to the area, etc.
```

into

```
He's
led
U.S.
efforts
for
management
resulting
in
approx.
3
times
the
missions
to
the
area
etc.
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?:          # match either...
 (?<![A-Z]   # (as long as not preceded by A-Z
  |\betc     # or etc
  |\bca      # or ca
  |\bapprox  # or approx
 )           # ...)
 \.          # a dot
 |           # or
 ,           # a comma
)?           # if present.
(\s+|$)      # then either match whitespace or the end of the string.
```

Comment: Thanks to all for answers. how can we have that hyphen included like "self-centered"?

Comment: @user482742: What do you mean? Do you want to split on the hyphen, too, unlike in your example above where `government-centered` remains together?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have a hard time distinguishing between `etc.` and `area.` (Or, as in your example, `U.S.` and `area.`. Also consider a sentence like "He has led multiple efforts in the U.S.", where you don't double the period at the end of a sentence. The best you'll get is close.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the regexp flavor you're using, you can go with the following:

```
/\b(\S+[^,.])\b/
```

As an alternative, you replace the `[^,.]` with Unicode codepoints `\P{P}`.

**EDIT:**

A much simpler expression works on the word level, but it will match `U.S` instead of `U.S.`:

```
/\w\S+\w/
```

Answer (score 1):

For the `U.S.` you need to specify that bareword in the regex. So your regex will be like:

```
\s?(U\.S\.|.*?)[., ]
```

That worked for me.